# Apache load balance

Tags: apache

4, I tried configuring load balancer in apache web server but unsuccessfully.

In my httpd.conf

```xml
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

<VirtualHost mysuperwebapp.com:80>
    ServerName mysuperwebapp.com
    <Location /balancer-manager>
        SetHandler balancer-manager
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from .mysuperwebapp.com
    </Location>
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        BalancerMember http://localhost:9999
        BalancerMember http://localhost:9998 status=+H
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy *>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9998/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I start the apache service, it said that

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 184 of /Users/aptos/Documents/workspace/Webserver/conf/httpd.conf:
BalancerMember Can't find 'byrequests' lb method
```

Can somebody show me where I did incorrectly?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 36):

In my case, I got the error **`ProxyPass Can't find 'byrequests' lb method`** as I using `proxy_balancer_module` module

Error is due to the fact that I missed to uncomment below required modules in httpd.conf

`LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so`

*and*

`LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so`

Un commenting above module entries, which are commented by default, in httpd.conf file solved my issue.

*(using Apache 2.4.3)*

Comment: worked with `a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests slotmem_shm`

Answer (score 8):

You need to load the mod_proxy_balancer. On distros which support it, the best way is to use a2enmod:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
```

It does all the work for you.

Comment: mod_lbmethod_byrequests were dissociated from mod_proxy_balancer from version 2.4 as per doc : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.html

Comment: To enable mod_lbmethod_byrequests in 2.4: run this: `a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests`

Answer (score 4):

On Apache 2.2, you will need these libraries instead:

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable below modules in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file.

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is to include

```
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
```

Or for IBM WebSPhere

```
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/WebSphereCE/mod_proxy_balancer.so
```